# Unable to perform activity in main tab after switching back from a new tab in same browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried opening a new tab in same browser by using the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

Performed some activity in new tab
again i tried switching back to previous/main tab by using the code:

```
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();// back to prev tab
```

now I am unable to perform any activity on previous/main tab after switching back to it from the new tab.

Comment: What exception/error it fire when you try to perform activity after switch back.

Comment: its showing Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"otp"}

Comment: whereas that ia the correct locator cause its running if i am running it in new class or commenting tab line

Comment: Can you share that web page link from which are trying to find element?

Comment: i am using correct locator only but after performing task in new tab & the again switching back to old tab i am not able to do it